# Entropy of a single Hint

Tags: probability-theory, entropy

Assume that the probability that a woman is above 80 years old is 3 times that of a man. How much information (in bits) do you get if you are given that a 80 year old person is a male?

How should I approach such a question? I have learned about entropy and how to measure it but do not see any way to apply this knowledge to this question.

Comment: Hint: What is the *probability* that a given 80 year old person is male?

Comment: I think I got it now: $P(f) = 3*P(m)$. Also: $P(f) + P(m) = 1$. From this: $3*P(m) + P(m) = 1 \implies P(m) = 1/4$. Now I guess I just have to use the [Entropy Formula for an Event](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Entropy_(information_theory)). Thank you very much!